# Generating every possible combination between two alphanumeric string ranges

Tags: c#, .net

I am working with SAP Idocs, which have segments which can contain cost centre reference ranges. The ranges are given as start and end values as strings. To store those values in my DB I need to generate all possible combinations existing between these values.

The strings are alphanumeric, say start: `D98C1` and end: `D9AZ3`. The individual char sequence is first numeric from 0 to 9 and then alphabetic from A to Z. The expansion needs to generate all possible combinations between start and end, like say start: `A1` to end: `CA` would comprise the values `A1` to `A9`, `AA` to `AZ`, `B0` to `B9`, `BA` to `BZ`, `C0` to `C9` and `CA`.

I am completely stuck on this and would really appreciate some pointers as to how this can be implemented.

EDIT:

As a person, I would start with finding the parts between the start and end strings which differ. I can do that, that's easy. So for the example above, that would be `D9`. Then I would go through the variable part of the start string one char at a time and vary all chars from the end of the string, going through all possible chars until I reach the corresponding char in the end string.

I'm just stuck implementing that.

I started out with something like this:

```
readonly static char[] values = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToArray(); 

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string from = "D3A0";

        string to = "D3AC";

        string root = new string(from.TakeWhile((c, i) => to.Length >= i && to[i] == c).ToArray());

        string from1 = from.Substring(root.Length);

        string to1 = to.Substring(root.Length);

        var output = new List<string>();

        for (int i = from1.Length - 1; i == 0; i--)
        {
            char startChar = from1[i];

            char endChar = to1[i];

            var remainingValues = values.SkipWhile(v => v != startChar)
                                        .TakeWhile(v => v != endChar)
                                        .ToList();

            foreach (char v in remainingValues)
            {
                string currentValue = from1.Remove(i) + v;

                output.Add(currentValue);
            }

            if (output.Contains(to1))
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        foreach (var s in output.Select(o => root + o))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
```

But it does not provide all combinations.

Comment: Thanks for the downvotes. Can I have an explanation?

Comment: I am actually, genuinely stuck on implementing this and would appreciate some help. I thought that's what SO is for...

Comment: So what did you try and where are you stuck? What *can* you do and what are you having problems with? Can you turn an "A" into a "B" into a "C"?

Comment: I said all that. I am actually completely stuck as to how to implement this. I can vary one char, but not generate the whole range of possible chars.

Comment: Always start with how you as a human would do it.

Comment: @nvoigt I've specified all that. I've added some code snippet now, but it is so wrong it's actually embarrassing.

Comment: So basically it's a simple counter, except your digits are `0` to `z` instead of the usual `0` to `9`, and you just start in x and end in y. I would start with a string (or a char array) containing all possible digits in the correct order.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I have an array containing all valid chars. Where I'm stuck is how to generate all the combinations between the string ranges and not just all possible combinations.

Comment: @yu_ominae your values array wouldnt be right. you said go from 0-9 and A-Z as Z is in your final string. yours only goes to E..

Comment: @BugFinder, you are completely right. That was just for testing purposes in my code, to explore the concept. I'll amend that now.

Comment: Wow, thank you for all the answers! I'll have go through and test them all now.

Comment: @yu_ominae I think you got a lot of down votes initially because it is a simple problem and people expected better of someone with 5 golds

Comment: @BugFinder I guess so. The thing is that I'm not good with CodeWars style problems and the golds are mainly for getting a lot of views on some of my questions over the years. My gold badges are meaningless if you ask me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
public static string Next(string current)
{
    if (current.EndsWith("Z"))
        return Next(current.Substring(0, current.Length - 1)) + "0";
    if (current.EndsWith("9"))
        return current.Substring(0, current.Length - 1) + "A";
    return current.Substring(0, current.Length - 1) + (char) (current[current.Length-1] + 1);
}
```

and then call it like this

```
var value = "A1";
while (value != "CB")
{
    Console.WriteLine(value);
    value = Next(value);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that just change the last char?

Comment: No. It calls itself recursively if other chars need to change. So after 'BZZZ' comes 'C000'.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer, as it is easy to follow :)
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5):

What you are looking for is called **base36**. Because it's a number that's represented in a 36 letter alphabet. As with any other representation of a number, you convert all representations to numbers, do your calculations and then convert them back for display:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp11
{
    public static class Base36
    {
        private const string Digits = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

        public static string ConvertToBase36(this int value)
        {
            string result = string.Empty;

            while (value > 0)
            {
                result = Digits[value % Digits.Length] + result; 
                value /= Digits.Length;
            }

            return result;
        }

        public static int ConvertFromBase36(this string value)
        {
            return value.Reverse().Select((character, index) => (int)Math.Pow(Digits.Length, index) * Digits.IndexOf(character)).Sum();
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var start = "D3A0";
            var end = "D3AC";

            var startNumber = start.ConvertFromBase36();
            var endNumber = end.ConvertFromBase36();

            while (startNumber < endNumber)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(startNumber.ConvertToBase36());
                startNumber++;
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This solution looks very good too. Thank you very much! I'm going to mark the other one as answer for now as I'm actually having trouble following what your method does and anybody who maintains my codebase in the future will probably also have trouble following it... sorry.

Comment: I'm actually getting an overflow error when trying to use this on a string pair like `VTB_TEST_1` to `VTB_TEST_C` (actual values I have to deal with in my data).

Comment: So what are the underscores supposed to be?

Comment: They are not supposed to do anything. They should just be ignored. I can see that your method cannot do that as it encodes and decodes the entire string (which is perfectly correct of course).
The problem in my case is that my client hasn't really specified what format the bounding strings can take, and I just found some data with underscores now.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
private static string values = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

public static void Main()
{
    string from = "Y5";

    string to = "ZZ";

    var counter = from;
    var output = new List<string>();
    while(counter != to) {
        counter = Increment(counter);
        output.Add(counter);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, output));
}

private static string Increment(string counter){
    if(counter.Length < 1) {
        counter = values[0] + counter;
    }

    var lastChar = counter[counter.Length - 1];
    var lastCharIndex = values.IndexOf(lastChar);

    if(lastCharIndex == -1)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Sequence contains an invalid character: " + lastChar);
    }

    var nextCharIndex = values.IndexOf(lastChar) + 1;

    if(nextCharIndex >= values.Length)
    {
        return Increment(counter.Substring(0, counter.Length - 1)) + values[0];
    }

    return counter.Substring(0, counter.Length - 1) + values[nextCharIndex];
}
```

Should work with any combination / order of values.

Answer (score 0):

I knocked up the following - as a first effort - values gets set to available character options.   This is how humans would do it.  Its not efficient, its not glorious, but it does the job.

```
   private static readonly char[] values = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' };

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Start: ");
        //String start = Console.ReadLine();
        String start = "D98C1";
        Console.Write(" End: ");
        String end = "D9AZ3";
        //String end = Console.ReadLine();
        int i1 = Array.IndexOf(values, start[0]);
        int i2 = Array.IndexOf(values, start[1]);
        int i3 = Array.IndexOf(values, start[2]);
        int i4 = Array.IndexOf(values, start[3]);
        int i5 = Array.IndexOf(values, start[4]);


        while (String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}", values[i1], values[i2], values[i3], values[i4], values[i5]) != end)
        {
            i5++;
            if (i5 == values.Length)
            {
                i5 = 0;
                i4++;
                if (i4 == values.Length)
                {
                    i4 = 0;
                    i3++;
                    if (i3 == values.Length)
                    {
                        i3 = 0;
                        i2++;

                        if (i2 == values.Length)
                        {
                            i2 = 0;
                            i1++;

                            if (i1 == values.Length)
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}", values[i1], values[i2], values[i3], values[i4], values[i5]));
        }
    }
```